# How to INSERT data to Vici storage in window phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my project, i want to add data :

```
"\n<p>sadasdasdsad</p>"
```

i use :

```
CSParameterCollection parameters = new CSParameterCollection();
                        parameters.Add("@title", f.Title.ToString());
                        parameters.Add("@sumary", f.Summary.ToString());
                        parameters.Add("@link[",f.Links[0].Uri.ToString());
                        parameters.Add("@datetime", f.PublishDate.ToString());
                        parameters.Add("@cid", idCate.ToString());
                        CSDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO Acticle (title,sumary,link,datetime,cid) VALUES ('@title','@sumary','@link','@datetime','@cid')",parameters);
```

but nerver complete .

Please help me !

Comment: What means "never completes"? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look at that, you have

```
parameters.Add("@link[",f.Links[0].Uri.ToString());
```

Do you need that **[** in there, after @link, or is it a typo?